# Visual Studio 2017 - deploy to Azure Function v2 (.NetCore v2.1) error: required process (“Web Management Service”) is started

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, azure-linux

I tried to deploy Functions Project in VS2017 to Azure Function (Linux). However, I faced below error:

> error : Could not connect to the remote computer (“XXX.scm.azurewebsites.net”). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process (“Web Management Service”) is started.

Comment: Can you try deleteing the publish profile and re-publishing it ? also mark the check mark in additional options `Delete old files before deployment`

Comment: hi @HariHaran, I tried but failed.

Comment: check if some answers from here help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518965/azure-function-app-publish-failed

Comment: It seems that the problem lies in your firewall and computer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> error : Could not connect to the remote computer
>   (“XXX.scm.azurewebsites.net”). On the remote computer, make sure that
>   Web Deploy is installed and that the required process (“Web Management
>   Service”) is started.

This error comes from the connection port to Azure. When you use VS to deploy Azure Functions but failed to connect to the port, the VS will return this error to you.

This doesn't mean that your WebDeploy Service is not running.

**Solution:**

***First solution:*** Have a check of the firewall, proxy server, other network settings or simply, use another machine directly under another network.

***Second solution:*** Change the value of **`WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM`** in the Application Settings of your website on portal to **`false`**, then download the publish setting in VS.

Comment: Able to deploy using second option but can't see any function on portal also not able  access with the endpoint. Can you please help on that