# Azure DevOps Releases: Error- Failed to deploy web package to App Service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, continuous-deployment, .net-6.0

I have created a .Net6 function app project and created a pipeline in the Azure DevOps. Whenever I push a new changes the Releases throws the following error aftar pipeline completed. .

[image: THis is]

The deployment is success if I disconnet the deplyment process in the Deploymenter Center from Azure App Service portal and click on the Create Release manually as shown below

[image]

Where I did go wrong? What's the solution if it has to trigger and get succeeded automatically without any additional work like disconnecting it and re-trying it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, during the continuous deployment, deployment methods will make changes to the `/home/site/wwwroot` folder files of the application which are used to run your application.

Sometimes the application might behave unpredictably during deployment because at the same time, the files aren't all updated.

Please find the below steps if they help to fix the issue:

- Try setting the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to `0` on the application settings. Refer to this [fix/workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58610195) from the similar kind of issue.
- **`WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM`** in the Application Settings to `False` of the Azure Function App Configuration.
- Stop the current running application or enable offline mode for it during deployment.
- Deploy the new changes to the staging slot with swap to the production if everything is working well.